# Can we segregate data used based on the View Results in tree Listener?

Tags: jmeter

We have used let say 500 different data for the same operation and out of which 250 are failed and other 250 is passed.
Do we have any script or method so that i can modify something in property file and segregate that failed data and write that data in some csv or excel file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two [View Results tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listeners, with two separate files.

One with `Log/Display Only:` field mark as `Errors` and other as `Successes`.

This way errors and successes will be segregated.

Comment: Thanks.....But how can I write the test data which has failed to any particular file.

Comment: The filename marked as `Errors` will save only failed samplers

Comment: Only sample results are getting written in that file.I wanted the test data that has been used to be writtyen in that

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. You can store [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) values for each sample result using simple configuration like:

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   sample_variables=foo,bar
   ```
2. Next time when you run a JMeter test you will see 2 new extra columns in .jtl results file, `foo` and `bar` which will hold the values for the relevant JMeter variables.

This way you will be able to figure out what data presumably causes failure (if it is connected with the input data).

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Results File Configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)